# Blocking IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a web app that will only support Chrome, Firefox and Safari. There are many methods out there for blocking browsers. I wanted to see what might be the best most efficient way of ensuring that only these browsers are granted access.

Thanks

Comment: Pick one. If it works, it's good.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the specific features you need that are not available in IE, then the best way to detect a capable browser is to do a feature test to see if those features are available or not.  This method is not spoofable and if, at some point in the future, IE starts supporting those feature, your app will just start working there.

Since you're using jQuery, you can look at [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) to see all the feature detection properties that it has already presented you.

If you don't want to do it the feature-detection way and you want to detect browser family, you can use any one of the browser detection methods.  The most common is to just look at the user agent string.  You should realize that the user agent string is settable or spoofable in many environments so it is not a conclusive indicator of the browser engine.  For normal users, it will likely be accurate, but can be messed with.

Here's a piece of code from Microsoft on detecting IE and various versions of IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the UA string and deny access via apache, js, php, whatever.
However you cannot ensure that what's labeled "firefox" actually is firefox - the UA header may contain whatever you like.

The other way is to do a feature test like it's used within common js frameworks. But remember that this will not work if your client's js is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This would typically involve checking the user agent of the visitor who is using your web application and blocking access to user agents you don't want to use. You could check the user agent in JavaScript (which would only work if the user had JavaScript enabled). Take a look at this page for information on the user agent property that you could check with JavaScript: [navigator.userAgent Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp). Alternatively you could check this server side with something like PHP. Take a look at [this page](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm) for more info on accessing the user agent of the user via PHP. You would be looking to check if the user agent contained the string "MSIE" or the other way around (e.g. checking that it either contains Gecko (for browsers that use the firefox rendering engine) or WebKit for Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I would also  recommend using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect browser functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I created a page: allowed.php

```
<?php 

$browser = 'Crap';

if( preg_match("/firefox/i",getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT")) && preg_match("/firefox/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ){
   $browser = 'Firefox';
}

if( preg_match("/chrome/i",getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT")) && preg_match("/chrome/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ){
    $browser = 'Chrome';
}

switch( $browser ){
case 'Firefox':
    // allowed
    break;
case 'Chrome':
    // allowed
    break;
default:
    Header("Location: rejects.html");
    exit();
}

//
```

And the rejects page: rejects.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Browser Rejects</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    margin:0px; width:100%; height:100%;
}
body {
    margin:0px; width:100%; height:100%;
}
.div-center { position:absolute; 
   margin:10% 20% auto 20%; padding:2%;
   border:1px solid #AAA; border-radius:10px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div-center">
When your Browser(or the Idiots that make it) learn(s) to abide to     Standards set by Society(e.g. W3C),<br>
We will then allow your Browser to be used on Our Sites.<br>
<br>
Until then, Please use a Real Web Browser like Firefox or Chrome.<br>
Thank You and have a Great Day !
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I place these both at the base of the specific web, and just use include allowed.php, filters out the crap browser...

~ SpaceCorp Innovative Technologies